# ee4 Save and close redirecting to /admin.php?/cp/addons/settings/structure/index

Tags: structure, ee4

Just one of my channels is misbehaving.  When editing a channel entry and clicking on "Save & Close" it redirects me to /admin.php?/cp/addons/settings/structure/index

1. I do not have an admin.php on the site, I renamed it.
2. What is causing this one channel to behave like this?  Is there anywhere I should look to check the settings or the like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you've set this as a setting in structure. it says something like redirect to structure after save. Might also be that your admin page is still defined as admin.php in either your renamed admin.php or the config.php or the config settings in the cp

Comment: The url to my admin page was indeed incorrectly set in master config.  I'm amazed to think how the system was working at all!